# Android Studio Getting Error while run App

Tags: android, android-studio

Getting error while run android application in Android Studio
This is my Logcat :

```
 Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not add entry '0' to cache localClassSetAnalysis.bin (F:\SATISH BackUp\Android 2016\EdulocationApp\.gradle\2.14.1\tasks\_app_compileDebugJavaWithJavac\localClassSetAnalysis\localClassSetAnalysis.bin).
Information:BUILD FAILED 
Information:Total time: 17.616 secs  
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: post app code .

Comment: check logcat for errors and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Sol. 1)
Set the JAVA_HOME in Environment Variables like this...
Variable Name: JAVA_HOME
Variable Value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111

Sol. 2)
Set the SDK location in project settings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb6A3.png)

Comment: Ping the screen shot of the log

Comment: Glad you could help me.Am just delete and create same project,Problem has been resolved.